# Python how to loop through a group of lists to get the specific indexes of the lists

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am newbie. I am learning web scraping so decided to **scrape** some coronavirus data. I want to get each countries name and reported cases which is index 0 and 1 in each list. how do i loop to get that. I read i can use Selenium to automate the data I can do with some help on this. thanx

```
import requests
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
page = requests.get(url)
page.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
table = soup.find('div', class_='main_table_countries_div')
data = table.find_all('tr')
row_list = list()
for tr in data:
   td = tr.find_all('td')
   row = [i.text for i in td]
   row_list.append(row)

for a in row_list:
   country_data = a
   print(country_data)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the lists is empty, causing an error when you try to index it:

```
import requests
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
page = requests.get(url)
page.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
table = soup.find('div', class_='main_table_countries_div')
data = table.find_all('tr')
row_list = list()
for tr in data:
   td = tr.find_all('td')
   row = [i.text for i in td]
   row_list.append(row)

# this is erroring out because the first list is empty
print(row_list[0])
for a in row_list[1:]:
   country_data = a
   # then you can access them by index
   print(country_data[0])
   print(country_data[1])
```

It's worth noting you're re-inventing the wheel. If you're doing that on purpose to learn, cheers, if not, have a look at the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library to manage frames of data.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, only thing you need to do on top of what you have done is to extract country name and reported count.

Your `row_list` is list of each row in the table, so you can just do:

```
country = []
reported = []
for a in row_list:
    if len(a) > 1:
        country.append(a[0])
        reported.append(a[1])
```

I added a check for `len(a) > 1` because I think the first row in `row_list` is empty. Then `country` and `reported` will be list of countries and the reported count for each country in the same order.

```
for c, r in zip(country ,reported):
    print("{}: {}".format(c, r))


USA: 159,689
Italy: 101,739
Spain: 85,195
Germany: 66,125
France: 44,550
Iran: 41,495
UK: 22,141
Switzerland: 15,760
Belgium: 11,899
Netherlands: 11,750
Turkey: 10,827
S. Korea: 9,661
Austria: 9,597
Canada: 7,297
Portugal: 6,408
...
```

Comment: you are a life saver. Thank you